# Are there any permanent points in ATP/WTA rankings?

Tags: tennis, ranking, atp, wta

For example: Nadal finished 1st at the end of 2013. **If, by assumption, he doesn't win any match in 2014** will he have 0 (or under 500 points - assuming that qualifing to the main table of tournaments grands you points) or there are some points for being so good in the past years that can't be erased?

I'm asking because Serena Williams hasn't shined at all this year (no important title) but it's still far away in the top, and it's only one Grand Slam left and it's the middle of the year.

Comment: Check out the points Serena has won in 2014. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_Serena_Williams_tennis_season She has won 3 titles this year

Answer (score 3):

You are correct - if Nadal didn't win a single match in 2014 his points total would fall back down to zero eventually.

Depending on the reason **why** a player isn't able to play for a long time (illness, injury, etc.) sometimes qualifies them to receive a protected ranking - read more about that [here](http://www.atpworldtour.com/Rankings/Rankings-FAQ.aspx#protected).